# How to get id value from url in php

Tags: php

http://localhost/users/delete.php/2

how can i get id value from this type of url in php

Thanks in advance

Comment: any framework you used?

Comment: @BhargavChudasama You can't answer this question without any of the code or context. There are hundreds of `.htaccess` creators. Also, this is a super dupe candidate. `:)`

Comment: @BhargavChudasama no i am not using any framework

Comment: @shubhangijain so what was the issue to getting id

Comment: @BhargavChudasama how can i get its value 2 from this url "http://localhost/users/delete.php/2"......

Comment: @shubhangijain where is come from this url? or you make manually this url?

Comment: @BhargavChudasama actually i am creating an api in php and the front end site they are sending id in the url like this "http://localhost/users/delete.php/2"

Comment: @shubhangijain can you make this way `localhost/users/delete.php?id=2`

Comment: no if i can make it in this way then i can easily find out id using $_GET....

Comment: @shubhangijain so why you not make this way any reason?

Comment: @shubhangijain Can you kindly look at the dupe I tagged?